# Need help migrating directive to Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have a directive called `NgtsAjax`, the directive makes a ajax request to an url passed on `path` attribute, you can use this way:

```
<ngts-ajax path="/api/customer/{{customerId}}" as="customer" on-success="ctrl.load(customer)" />
```

The directive factory is:

```
function NgtsAjaxFactory() {
    return {    
        restrict: "E",
        bindToController: true,
        scope: {
            url: "@path",
            as: "=as",
            httpVerb: "@verb",
            onFail: "&onFail",
            onSuccess: "&onSuccess"
        },
        controller: NgtsAjax,
        priority: 20000
    }
}
```

The directive uses the `path` attribute, binded to `url`, in a special way I'm going to explain it.

I get the `url` value and detect if has *parameters* using moustache syntax, if uses it I get each parameter and I keep on a parameter list called `pathVariables`, by last I observe the `path` attribute for changes, when `path` is changed I check if each parameter in `pathVariables` has value and it all have values and use $http to run ajax request.

These are the relevant pieces of code of controller:

```
class NgtsAjax {
    //... class attributes
    //...
    constructor($scope, private $interpolate, private $attrs, ....)
        this.pathAttr = $attrs.path;
        ....
        ....
        this.parentScope = $scope.$parent;
        this.observePath();
    }

    private observePath() {
        if (!this.url)
            this.url = this.$location.path();
            this.pathVariables = [];
        else {
            // Gets variables in path attribute
            const pathVariables = this.pathVariables = this.pathAttr.match(/{{[\w.\s|:$']+}}/g) || [];
            if (pathVariables) {
                for (let i = 0; i < pathVariables.length; i++) {
                    pathVariables[i] = pathVariables[i].toString();
                }
            }
        }
        this.$attrs.$observe("path", () => {
            if (this.pathVariablesHaveValues())
                this.run();
        });
    }

    private pathVariablesHaveValues() {
        let result = true;
        const pathVariables = this.pathVariables;
        for (let i = 0; i < pathVariables.length; i++) {
            const interpolation = pathVariables[i];
            const expression = this.$interpolate(interpolation);
            if (!expression(this.parentScope)) {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

I do it this way because path attribute can have several variables/expressions, for example:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model.customerId"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="model.invoiceId"/>

<ngts-ajax path="/api/customer/{{model.customerId}}/invoice/{{model.invoiceId}}" as="customerInvoice" on-success="ctrl.load(customerInvoice)" />
```

In order to make the ajax request I have to be sure that `customerId` and `invoiceId` have values.

You can look at the full directive source code [here](https://github.com/tolemac/ngts-module/blob/master/ajax.ts).

Then, I'm not sure how to approach the implementation of this, I'm not sure if it have to be a @Directive or a @Component and I'm have no idea how to resolve  the variables issue on the path.

Wich do you think is the best approach?

**Update 1**: The question is not if use Directive or Component ... the problem is the `path` attribute behaivor.

**Update 2**: A middle/hacking/patching/... solution.

I have insert a little restriction to make it works I force to write variables on `path` between square brackets ([]) this way:

```
<em-ajax path="/api/customer/[{{model?.customerId}}]/invoice/[{{model?.invoiceId}}]"></em-ajax>
```

With this I can determinate if the variables are empty looking for "[]".

I have defined the directive this way:

```
@Directive({
    selector: "em-ajax",
})
export class EmAjax implements OnChanges {
    @Input() path : string;
    ...
    ...

    ngOnChanges() {
        if (this.pathIsValid()) {
            this.run();
        }
    }

    pathIsValid() {
        if (this.path.indexOf("[]") >= 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    run(params? : any) {
        let path = this.path.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
        // `path` is the real url
        // I can launch http request
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

If you know other way to do it better, let me know ;)

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between component and directive is, that a component has a view. I assume that it should be an invisible behavior only element and you don't need a view. Therefore go with `Directive`.

Comment: Ok, but the real problem is the behavior with `path` attribute.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is about. Maybe you want to make the input a setter `@Input() set path(value:string) { ... }` to execute some code when the value is updated or implement `ngOnChanges()` which is called when an input value changes.